# Does elementary particle emit photon?

Tags: magnetic-fields, charge, collision, particle-detectors, particle-accelerators

Charged particles are accelerated by the magnetic field in a particle collider before allowed to smash together at specific location where the detectors are housed. My question is do the byproducts(elementary particles such as higgs boson) emit photons as they are produced to be filmed on tape by the sensitive detectors? or do these detectors pick up disturbance in the magnetic field(hence do all elementary particles contain charges)? also note that the physicists working at the particle collider are able to see the collision real time in 3d on their screen[1].

1 [The Large Hadron Collider Explained by DNews pause at 1:57](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwNwCs2CH7w) please pay attention to the top left corner of the video stating recorded date and time

Comment: *"also note that the physicists working at the particle collider are able to see the collision real time in 3d on their screen.*" [citation needed]

Comment: Charged particles will be accelerated by electric fields. By the help of magnetic field it's possible to change the direction of moving particles only.

Comment: Event displays are commonly near-real time. I've worked on experiments where the delay was seconds and others where it was minutes. I've no actual experience with the online display at a LHC experiment so I won't hazard a guess as to how close to real-time they are. Part of the issue depends on how much processing you want. Where it is seconds the display is generally simply of what detector elements are activated and how much. If you want tracking you generally have to wait a little longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is do the byproducts(elementary particles such as higgs
>   boson) emit photons as they are produced to be filmed on tape by the
>   sensitive detectors?

If you're imagining that the particles are emitting photons as the leave the collision center and that the tracks of the particles on the computer screen were recorded by collecting these photons, then the answer is no.

[Bubble chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chamber) do make the trajectories visible since the particle interacts with the liquid leaving an ionization trail that causes microscopic bubbles that can be photographed.

[Spark chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_chamber) do make the trajectories visible as a line of sparks.

The tracking detectors at the LHC are designed to interact with the particles directly in such a way that the trajectory of a particle from the collision region to the detector can be reconstructed numerically and then displayed via computer graphics.

See this article "[How a detector works](http://home.web.cern.ch/about/how-detector-works)".  An excerpt::

> Tracking devices reveal the paths of electrically charged particles as
>   they pass through and interact with suitable substances. Most tracking
>   devices do not make particle tracks directly visible, but record tiny
>   electrical signals that particles trigger as they move through the
>   device. A computer program then reconstructs the recorded patterns of
>   tracks.